# Regex - How to parse data when there are multiple brackets?

Tags: php, regex

All-

I love regex quite a bit, but when there are multiple types of parsing I get quite confused.

I'm basically trying to parse data such as this:

```
{"classs":15,"commondrop":true,"id":7101,"level":1,"name":"7Z",
 "slot":0,"source":[2],"subclass":0, 
 modes: { "mode":4,
          "4": { "count":15862,"outof":36461 }
        },
 count:15862, stack:[1,1]
}, 
{"classs":15,"commondrop":true,"id":62530,"level":1,"name":"7Z",
 "slot":0,"source":[2],"subclass":0,
  modes:{ "mode":4,
          "4":{ "count":13402,"outof":36461 }
        },
  count:13402,stack:[1,1]
},
{"classs":15,"commondrop":true,"id":3300,"level":5,"name":"7Rabbit's Foot",
 "slot":0,"source":[2],"subclass":0,
  modes:{"mode":4,
         "4":{ "count":1,"outof":36461 }
        },
  count:1,stack:[1,1] 
}
]});
```

Since there are sub brackets (the { and }) I'm not entirely sure how to ONLY get what is in the outter bracket. So I would just want to get this out of it:

```
"classs":15,"commondrop":true,"id":7101,"level":1,"name":"7Z","slot":0,"source":[2],"subclass":0,modes:{"mode":4,"4":{"count":15862,"outof":36461}},count:15862,stack:[1,1]
```

(which I could then parse further and break it down more)

Is this even possible with regex?  I started off trying something like `\{"classs"(.*?)\},{` but it misses some of the data.

Comment: This looks like JSON. Why don't you just use a JSON parser, e.g. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php?

Comment: And now that seems like a `JSON`. So use a `json parser` instead of `Regex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

counting brackets is not possible with regular expressions, because these aren't regular languages. The solution will be to use i.e. a Parsing Expression Grammar implementation instead of a RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is terrible at handling any kind of nesting, and as far as I know it is impossible to anything that can be recursively nested.  Instead you should use an appropriate parser.  What you have appears to be JSON (although it is invalid .. I assume what you have pasted is incomplete).  PHP has a built in function to parse this, [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: Can't use this because of the [], it's a parameter passed to a function so it will never decode.  I wish it was that simple :/

Answer (score 0):

Why not use json_decode() ?
That return an array and you can count or foreach it.